# Crashes on iOS 14 beta showing <redacted> on desymbolication in Firebase crashlytics

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-beta

Why suddenly my crash logs are coming with  on iOS 14 beta crashes only? How can I get the proper desymbolicated crash logs? I am using the firebase crashlytics as crash logging tool and it is working fine for crashes happening on ios version 13.x or lower.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1872ca8e0 <redacted> + 60
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1872b5424 <redacted> + 68
2  UIKitCore                      0x18b75197c <redacted> + 372
3  UIKitCore                      0x18b74fe7c <redacted> + 636
4  UIKitCore                      0x18b74fbd8 <redacted> + 216
5  UIKitCore                      0x18b7511f8 <redacted> + 100
6  UIKitCore                      0x18b751268 <redacted> + 80
7  UIKitCore                      0x18b74ea3c <redacted> + 40
8  UIKitCore                      0x18b74e5a8 <redacted> + 3708
9  UIKitCore                      0x18b74d70c <redacted> + 164
10 UIKitCore                      0x18bd125e0 <redacted> + 132
11 UIKitCore                      0x18bd0d6bc <redacted> + 780
12 UIKitCore                      0x18c1e4fcc <redacted> + 164
13 WebKit                         0x18fc68c7c <redacted> + 152
14 WebKit                         0x18fed97e4 <redacted> + 148
15 UIKitCore                      0x18c1e5024 <redacted> + 68
16 UIKitCore                      0x18c1e50d4 <redacted> + 144
17 UIKitCore                      0x18c1e5774 <redacted> + 236
18 CoreAutoLayout                 0x1c95a0558 <redacted> + 88
19 UIKitCore                      0x18c1e5618 <redacted> + 836
20 UIKitCore                      0x18c1f4130 <redacted> + 2084
21 UIKitCore                      0x18b42a7f8 <redacted> + 572
22 UIKitCore                      0x18b42d834 <redacted> + 1404
23 UIKitCore                      0x18b432250 <redacted> + 5748
24 UIKitCore                      0x18b436af4 <redacted> + 324
25 UIKitCore                      0x18c1fa7d8 <redacted> + 2204
26 QuartzCore                     0x18f1c8a48 <redacted> + 296
27 QuartzCore                     0x18f1c8f04 <redacted> + 524
28 QuartzCore                     0x18f1dd2bc <redacted> + 144
29 QuartzCore                     0x18f1262e8 <redacted> + 416
30 QuartzCore                     0x18f1515ac <redacted> + 732
31 QuartzCore                     0x18f152900 <redacted> + 96
32 CoreFoundation                 0x18751e30c <redacted> + 36
33 CoreFoundation                 0x187518aa4 <redacted> + 520
34 CoreFoundation                 0x187518fbc <redacted> + 1060
35 CoreFoundation                 0x187518788 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 564
36 GraphicsServices               0x1933f3820 GSEventRunModal + 164
37 UIKitCore                      0x18bcd71d8 <redacted> + 1072
38 UIKitCore                      0x18bcdd0b8 UIApplicationMain + 1876
39 MagicBox Learning              0x102724c6c main + 14 (__hidden#14868_:14)
40 libdyld.dylib                  0x1873a43d4 <redacted> + 4
```

Answer (score 1):

This was caused due to an outage on the Firebase side. A banner should have been shipped to reflect this. The issue is being actively worked on, and will hopefully be resolved soon.

Comment: Thanks, @Oleg. Also is it mandatory to make an archive with new Xcode beta and upload to firebase app distribution so as to add the device support symbols for iOS 14 related crashes symbolication? So that for future crashes <redacted> or  (__hidden#14868_:14) will not come again.

Comment: No problem. All iOS 14 apps must be built on XCode 12, iOS 14 apps won't compile on Xcode 11.

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on a lot of crashes now that iOS 14 has launched. Any word on when Firebase will be able to get it fixed?

Comment: Also, there is no requirement to build apps with Xcode 12 until April 2021. I still have several compiler issues I have to work through before I can use Xcode 12 so I will probably continue shipping on Xcode 11 for a few weeks/months. However, users on iOS 14 will be downloading my app of course. I assume I should be able to get crash reports from them without <redacted> right?

Comment: Yep, you should continue to get crashes without missing frames.

Comment: Any idea why they are all still redacted then? Is there something I need to do to fix it?

Comment: As I understand, those frames don't get backfilled. After the symbols are uploaded from the Crashlytics end, you will need another crash to occur to confirm the stack trace does not contain missing frames.